# what is aexnsagent.exe?

Tags: windows, process

What is `aexnsagent.exe`?  It has made my PC run slower.

Answer (score 9):

These answers are only partially correct.

Yes, the AeXNSAgent.exe is the Altiris agent, which is part of the Altiris Client/Server Management Suites. This agent is used for systems management in many corporate environments. The purpose of this software is to manage software delivery, software patches, computer software/hardware inventory, remote assistance, and various other remote client management capabilities. They are now owned by Symantec.

The actual reason that it's making your PC run slow depends on a lot of things, but typically it's because the agent is misconfigured on the server. There are several things that could be going on, but here's the most likely problem.

The default installation of Altiris will run a Software Inventory, Hardware Inventory, and a Serial Number inventory on the endpoints (client machines) on a regular basis. The purpose of these inventory scans are to identify the software that is installed so it can perform patches and help ensure license compliance.

However, if the default settings are used, then when the Software Inventory executes it will iterate over every file on your file system as quickly as possible. The problem is that it will do this iteration as quickly as possible which pegs your disk I/O, slowing down everything. The solution is to enable what is called "Slow Mode" on the server. This instructs the agent to insert an artificial delay every 300 files or so. This delay is typically around 20ms, which is enough time to allow the disk to do other things and alleviates the "slowness".

Most people schedule this to run at 3am so it will happen when people aren't at their computers, but when you come into the office, you turn on the computer, the agent wakes up and sees that it never executed this task at 3am, so it immediately starts running the Software Inventory, pegging the disk I/O. When users get into the office, they boot up their computer and the first thing they typically do is check their email. This is most often where users see the "slowness".

Have your Altiris administrator enable Slow Mode for both the Software Inventory and Full Inventory scans and this issue should go away. It has NOTHING to do with bandwidth, nor is it part of Deployment Solution, as another posted indicated.

Answer (score 3):

It's part of an Altiris program that helps with the deployment of software. If its a work computer, it was likely installed by your companies IT department. (It also appears its used for the monitoring of peoples computers).

You can always go look for the "Enable Bandwidth Control" option and set it so it doesn't eat up as much of your resources.

Answer (score 1):

**Description:** File AeXNSAgent.exe is located in a subfolder of "C:\Program Files". Known file sizes on Windows XP are 1,277,952 bytes (35% of all occurrence), 1,257,472 bytes, 565,248 bytes, 552,960 bytes, 1,523,712 bytes, 512,000 bytes, 516,096 bytes, 544,768 bytes.

> File AeXNSAgent.exe is not a Windows system file. The application listens for or sends data on open ports to LAN or Internet. The program has no visible window. AeXNSAgent.exe is able to hide itself, monitor applications, record inputs. Therefore the technical security rating is 52% dangerous, however also read the users reviews.

**Important:** *Some malware camouflage themselves as AeXNSAgent.exe, particularly if they are located in c:\windows or c:\windows\system32 folder. Thus check the AeXNSAgent.exe process on your pc whether it is pest. We recommend Security Task Manager for verifying your computer's security. It is one of the Top Download Picks of 2005 of The Washington Post and PC World.*

> **Recommendations : Its not a critical component, but use some scanner for disabling it.**

source : http://www.file.net/process/aexnsagent.exe.html

Comment: I realize your link explains everything, but it seems that an obvious piece of information is missing from your answer. :)  I found myself thinking "yes, but what IS it??!?".

Comment: Yes I agree with your point . But i would like this information to reach every one in super user .